# array mapped, reduce, filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am still getting my head around these methods.
I have a set of nested arrays and I need to extract the **States** from them, currently I have this:

```
// For each group
groups.forEach(function (group) {

    // For each question
    group.questions.forEach(function (question) {

        // For each answer
        question.answers.forEach(function (answer) {

            // For each state
            answer.states.forEach(function (state) {

                // Push to our array
                states.push(state);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I am certain that I can do that in a much better way with the new array methods available to me.
Can someone give me a hand and let me know which one?

Comment: Iterating on `states` array while altering it's contents look awkward here.

Comment: it looks like you are headed in the right direction! Take a look at [this functional programming page](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)..

Comment: Can you give a short sample of the array (of arrays) with which you're working? That way we can see the input (the `groups` array) you're working with, and you can show us the exact output (from that sample data) that you expect. This allows us to offer more specific practical advice, rather than trying to guess.

Comment: surely that doesn't matter, the face that it is a nested array should suffice :o

Answer (score 0):

One way would be with a series of `reduce` operations.

```
groups.reduce((arr, group) => arr.concat(group.questions), [])
      .reduce((arr, question) => arr.concat(question.answers), [])
      .reduce((arr, answer) => arr.concat(answer.states), [])
```

This is functionally equivalent to your original solution which I prove in the snippet below:

```js
var groups = [{
  questions: [{
    answers: [{
      states: [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }, {
      states: [
        4,
        5,
        6
      ]
    }]
  }, {
    answers: [{
      states: [
        7,
        8,
        9
      ]
    }, {
      states: [
        10,
        11,
        12
      ]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  questions: [{
    answers: [{
      states: [
        13,
        14,
        15
      ]
    }, {
      states: [
        16,
        17,
        18
      ]
    }]
  }, {
    answers: [{
      states: [
        19,
        20,
        21
      ]
    }, {
      states: [
        22,
        23,
        24
      ]
    }]
  }]
}];

function yourMethod() {
  var states = [];
  // For each group
  groups.forEach(function (group) {
    // For each question
    group.questions.forEach(function (question) {
      // For each answer
      question.answers.forEach(function (answer) {
        // For each state
        answer.states.forEach(function (state) {
          // Push to our array
          states.push(state);
        });
      });
    });
  });
  return states;
}

function myMethod() {
  return groups.reduce((arr, group) => arr.concat(group.questions), [])
               .reduce((arr, question) => arr.concat(question.answers), [])
               .reduce((arr, answer) => arr.concat(answer.states), []);
}

var originalResult = yourMethod();
var newResult = myMethod();
console.log(originalResult.join(' ') === newResult.join(' '));
```

Comment: IMHO, most uses of `.reduce()` like this are more suited to CodeGolf than SO. And repeated `concat` makes it an N^2 algorithm, because every concatenation has to copy the two arrays.

Comment: @Barmar Absolutely right. I suppose I should specify that I find this easier to read but it's most definitely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

you could use recursivity if you deal with a pure array of arrays like this :

```
var result = [];
var seek = arr => {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) arr.forEach(subArray => seek(subArray));
    else result.push(arr);
} 
seek(groups)
console.log (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think your method is the most readable one. Other methods can be shorter, but they're usually harder to read.

Anyway, if you still need a cleaner solution, I recommend you to use ES6 for shortening the syntax.

```
for(let group of groups){
  for(let question of group.questions){
    for(let answer of question.answers){
      states.push(...answer.states);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that `for-of` is not available in many browsers that are still common.

Answer (score 0):

somewhat offtopic, but you can use `map` with combination of [_.flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#flattenDeep) from lodash:

```
_.flattenDeep(groups.map(g => g.questions.map(q => q.answers.map(a => a.states))));
```